# Showing $(1 + z\omega)(1 + \overline{z\omega}) \leq (1 + |z|^2)(1 + |\omega|^2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Consider the following inequality : $(1 + z\omega)(1 + \overline{z\omega}) \leq (1 + |z|^2)(1 + |\omega|^2)$.

I was reading an article which uses this inequality, and the reading said this was an elementary inequality. Maybe it is but I do not see how to prove it. The help would be appreciated if someone could show me how to verify this! $z$ and $\omega$ are complex numbers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
(1 + z\omega)(1 + \overline{z\omega}) &= 1 + z\omega + \overline{z\omega} + z\omega\overline{z\omega}\\
& = 1 + 2\operatorname{Re}(z\omega) + |z\omega|^2\\
& \le 1 + 2|z\omega| + |z\omega|^2\\
&= 1 + 2|z||\omega| + |z|^2 |\omega|^2\\
&\le 1 + (|z|^2 + |\omega|^2) + |z|^2 |\omega|^2\\
&= (1 + |z|^2)(1 + |\omega|^2).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

since $$0 \le (|z| - |w|)^2  \text{ gives you } 2|z||w| \le |z|^2 + |w|^2 \tag1 $$

all you need $$zw + \bar z\bar w  \le |zw + \bar z\bar w| \le |zw| + |\bar z\bar w| = 2|z||w| \tag 2$$ in the last inequality we used the triangle inequality.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $$(1+zw)(1+\bar z\bar w)=1+zw+\bar z \bar w + |z|^2|w|^2 \le 1+2|z||w| + |z|^2|w|^2 \le 1+|z|^2+|w|^2 + |z|^2|w|^2 = (1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2)$$